# If $mx=m$ for some (or all) integer $m$, then $x=1$

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic, axioms, integers

I am studying proofs, and I am stuck thinking about the logic behind these two propositions:

1. Let $x \in\mathbb Z$, if $x$ has the property the for all $m \in\mathbb Z$ $mx = m$, then $x=1$.
2. Let $x \in\mathbb Z$, if $x$ has the property the for some nonzero $m \in\mathbb Z$ $mx = m$, then $x=1$.

Here is a solution:

\begin{align*}
mx &= m \\
mx &= m \cdot 1 \\ 
x &= 1\\
\end{align*}

I can get the same solution for both propositions but the difference seems to be at the third step. For 1) I can simply simplified both m. 2) I can use the cancellation axion: Let $m,n$ and $p$ be integers. If $m \cdot n = m \cdot p$ and $m \ne 0$, then $n = p$.

However, I could be wrong and would appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you!

Comment: First of all cancellation is not usually taken to be an axiom (but it follows from the usual axioms). Secondly, you only need to prove 2) as 1) follows from 2) (but you need to check $m=0$ seperately).

Comment: Thank you! However, in the exercises, 1) comes before 2) and each proposition is meant to be proven sequentially.